# solving an equation about the number of divisors

Tags: number-theory

> Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $n=d(n)+1$

($d(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$)

Any ideas on how to solve this ???

Comment: This might be a good place to [start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_m^{a_m}$ with $a_i\ge1$, then $d(n)=(a_1+1)\cdots (a_m+1)$. 
We have $p^a\ge a+1$ for all $p\ge 2, a\ge 1$. In fact, $p^a=a+1$ holds only in one special case, namely $p=2,a=1$. Thus if $m>1$, the strict inequality  $p_i^{a_i}>a_i+1$ and hence $p_i^{a_i}\ge a_i+2$ holds for some $i$ and we get 
$$n\ge \prod_{j=1}^m (a_j+1) +  \prod_{j=1\atop j\ne i}^m (a_j+1)=d(n)+\prod_{j=1\atop j\ne i}^m (a_j+1)$$
The product on the right is $>1$ if $m>1$.
Therefore we get as necessary condition for $n=d(n)+1$ that $m=1$.
So we need to solve $p^a=a+2$, which has solutions $n=3$ and $n=4$.

Comment: @sacch Actually, on second thought, I like the ideas blf and anon had much better. If $n>4$, we have $\frac n2<n-2<n-1<n$, hence $n-2$ and $n-1$ are not divisors of $n$, which directly imlpies $d(n)\le n-2$ for $n>4$.